# Emulate copy-assignment operator for lambdas in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

This question has two parts

*Firstly*, can someone explain the rationale behind C++ disabling the copy-assignment operator for lambdas? If you're going to allow the copy constructor, why not the copy-assignment operator?

*Secondly*, how do you best overcome this limitation without forcing people to write C++03 style functors, or using std::function (the functions I'm dealing with are tiny, and I'd like the compiler to inline them wherever possible)?

**Background**:
I'm trying to implement a flat_map like operation in a [stream processing library I'm writing](https://github.com/foges/ftl), similar to flatMap in Scala or other functional languages. As a result, I need to create an iterator that iterates over a list of iterators. Each time the flat_map iterator is de-referenced a lambda associated with the inner iterator is executed. The outer iterator needs to switch the inner iterator each time the inner iterator reaches the end. Since the inner iterator contains a lambda, and therefore does not have a copy-assignment operator, it's not possible to switch it. Technically I could solve the problem using dynamic allocation, so that I always call the copy-constructor, but that doesn't seem like the right approach. Here is a snippet of code that might help highlight the problem:

```
template <typename Iter>
class flat_map_iterator {
public:
  flat_map_iterator& operator++() {
    ++it_inner_;
    if (it_inner_ == (*it_outer_).end()) {
      ++it_outer_;
      // ERROR: cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted
      it_inner_ = (*it_outer_).begin();
    }
    return *this;
  }
private:
  Iter it_outer_; 
  typename Iter::value_type::iterator it_inner_;
};
```

**Edit**:

Thanks for the really quick responses. Here is a use case example:

```
 int res = ftl::range(1, 4).map([](int a){
     return ftl::range(a, 4).map([a](int b){
         return std::make_tuple(a, b);
     });
 })
 .flat_map([](std::tuple<int, int> x){ return std::get<0>(x) * std::get<1>(x); })
 .sum();

 assert(res, 25);
```

The `ftl::range(begin, end)` function returns a lazy iterator over the range `[begin, end)`.

Comment: Please post a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including usage code with a lambda

Comment: "If you're going to allow the copy constructor, why not the copy-assignment operator". Lambda tend to store references. I don't think one can copy-assign references stored in object without some hacky tricks...

Comment: If you really don't want to use dynamic allocation, use optional and reconstruct it every time with the correct it_inner_ (instead of copy-assigning it).

Comment: Assignment would inhibit inlining anyway.

Comment: @W.F. Didn't think about lambdas storing references. Although this seems like it should depend on the arguments to the lambda?

Comment: @n.m. That's an interesting point. Is that true even if the value being assigned is a lambda to a pure function that only depends on its arguments?

Comment: It doesn't matter because a compiler will normally have an extremely hard time propagating values through assignment. If you say `if (cond) fptr = func1; else fptr = func2; while (...) { ... fptr(); ... }` then chances are nothing will be inlined, regardless of what fptr and func1 and func2 are: lambdas, function objects, or plain old functions/pointers. If you don't need to assign conditionally you can just use construction.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for clearing that up. It makes a lot of sense. For all the operations so far (map, reduce, filter, split, take, take_while, sorted, etc..) assignment is not necessary, and I've avoided it wherever possible. For flat_map it's fair enough that the compiler wont be able to inline it since each inner iterator could contain a fairly different set of elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not that C++ disables the copy-assignment operator for lambda per-se, but that by default members in a lambda object are saved as const, and then the assignment operator can basically do nothing to assign to them, and so it is not generated. If you want lambdas to *not* hold members as const, you use the `[...](...) mutable {...}` syntax.

The other thing is that I'm not entirely sure what you get out of assigning lambdas. I mean, if you're going to re-use the lambda type (and functionality) and simply bind it to different variables, you're already working against the nice lambda capture syntax, and might as well have it be a normal function object. *Assigning one type of lambda to another one is impossible.* This means that you can not provide different lambda implementations when you hold the lambda itself by value.

If this is *still* what you're going for, I think dynamic allocation (e.g. using `unique_ptr`) is fair game.

And if you really want to avoid it, you could manually destruct and re-construct your lambda, as the following [example](http://rextester.com/AUSA93624) illustrates:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct LambdaContainer {
    LambdaContainer(const T& lambda)
        : lambda{lambda} {}

    void resetLambda(const T& lambda) {
        this->lambda.~T();
        new (&this->lambda) T{lambda};
    }

    T lambda;
};

int main()
{
    int i = 1;

    auto l = [=]() {
        std::cout << i;
    };

    using LT = decltype(l);

    LambdaContainer<LT> lc{l};

    lc.resetLambda(l);
}
```

Comment: This looks like a neat solution. Implemented it and it looks like it compiles. Need to test it. I didn't know that members are stored as const by default, that clears up why copy-assignment won't work. It's not that I really want to re-assign lambdas, it's that I want iterators to contain lambdas. The nice lambda syntax makes it much easier to create these iterators.

Comment: I have a need for this as well. I want a no-heap version of std::function.

Comment: `mutable` does not make the data members const; it makes the call operator const, so that it can’t modify them.