# lambda deleter for unique_ptr causing compile error vs functor

Tags: c++, stl, unique-ptr

Feels like a basic question, but has me very confused.

I've been updating our codebase from VS2012 to VS2015, and we have a unique_ptr with a custom deleter defined like so:

```
auto cpcdeleter = []( CP_CONVERT * ptr ) { KillCpConvert( &ptr ); };
unique_ptr<CP_CONVERT, decltype( cpcdeleter )> cpc;

...

cpc = unique_ptr<CP_CONVERT, decltype( cpcdeleter )>( CreateCpConvert(), cpcdeleter );
```

I get an error in VS2015 complaining about the deleter having a deleted assignment operator so it can't perform the assignment. This assignment worked fine in VS2012, using the R-Value reference overload of operator=.

It all works fine if I define the deleter as a functor instead:

```
struct CpDeleter 
{ 
  public: 
    void operator()(CP_CONVERT *ptr) const { KillCpConvert( &ptr ); } 
};
```

Now I'm fine doing exactly that, but I was pretty sure that using a lambda should work. And it did until recently!

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: full error in all it's template glory

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\memory(1382): error C2280: 'openscheduleretrieve_ldlo::<lambda_b4b428a756e3b5d157dcc5597b762dc5> &openscheduleretrieve_ldlo::<lambda_b4b428a756e3b5d157dcc5597b762dc5>::operator =(const openscheduleretrieve_ldlo::<lambda_b4b428a756e3b5d157dcc5597b762dc5> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
fileopen.cpp(1625): note: see declaration of 'openscheduleretrieve_ldlo::<lambda_b4b428a756e3b5d157dcc5597b762dc5>::operator ='
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\memory(1378): note: while compiling class template member function 'std::unique_ptr<CP_CONVERT,openscheduleretrieve_ldlo::<lambda_b4b428a756e3b5d157dcc5597b762dc5>> &std::unique_ptr<CP_CONVERT,openscheduleretrieve_ldlo::<lambda_b4b428a756e3b5d157dcc5597b762dc5>>::operator =(std::unique_ptr<CP_CONVERT,openscheduleretrieve_ldlo::<lambda_b4b428a756e3b5d157dcc5597b762dc5>> &&) noexcept'
fileopen.cpp(1640): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::unique_ptr<CP_CONVERT,openscheduleretrieve_ldlo::<lambda_b4b428a756e3b5d157dcc5597b762dc5>> &std::unique_ptr<CP_CONVERT,openscheduleretrieve_ldlo::<lambda_b4b428a756e3b5d157dcc5597b762dc5>>::operator =(std::unique_ptr<CP_CONVERT,openscheduleretrieve_ldlo::<lambda_b4b428a756e3b5d157dcc5597b762dc5>> &&) noexcept' being compiled
fileopen.cpp(1626): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::unique_ptr<CP_CONVERT,openscheduleretrieve_ldlo::<lambda_b4b428a756e3b5d157dcc5597b762dc5>>' being compiled
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the *full* and *complete* copy-pasted error?

Comment: Considering that's a non-capturing lambda, you could use `void(*)(CP_CONVERT*)` as the deleter type. (And chances are you could then use `&KillCpConvert` directly).

Comment: @MSalters Except that `KillCpConvert` seems to be taking a pointer to the pointer as argument.

Comment: @YSC, don't be so categorical, he is unresponsive **so far**. This isn't an online chat. The man may solve some other problems of his own that time, rather than waiting the ansters which might not come. Be patient, dude ;)

Comment: @Alexey If someone asks an incomplete question on SO and doesn't answer comments asking for precision, their question typically falls into oblivion where it is not useful. SO is a Q&A based on some implicit principles: if you want an answer, take some time to groom your question.

Comment: The full error really isn't that useful, but as requested...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda isn't copy-assignable, therefore you cannot use the assignment here:

```
cpc = unique_ptr<CP_CONVERT, decltype( cpcdeleter )>( CreateCpConvert(), cpcdeleter );
```

So, do the following instead:

```
auto cpcdeleter = []( CP_CONVERT * ptr ) { KillCpConvert( &ptr ); };
// Initialize your smart pointer with nullptr and the deleter needed
unique_ptr<CP_CONVERT, decltype( cpcdeleter )> cpc(nullptr, cpcdeleter);

...

// Then set the desired pointer
cpc.reset(CreateCpConvert());
```

Comment: Interesting - lambdas aren't copy assignable - why is that? I'd have assumed lambdas would be copy assignable unless they captured anything by reference. I think I need to crack open the standard and have a look.

Comment: @RichardMatheson, I wonder the same. Can't figure out any reasons for this behavior in that case, heeding that you mentioned that everything's fine in VS2012...

Comment: There has been changes between C++11 and C++14, which might account for the copying being disallowed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379369/emulate-copy-assignment-operator-for-lambdas-in-c - basically all memebers are const so can be copy constructed, but not copy assigned. Doh! Probably this was a conformance fix to the compiler.