# Rationale behind deleting lambda assignment operator?

Tags: c++, lambda

I just learned that a (even `mutable`) lambda in C++ is [not assignable unless it has empty captures](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (c.f. `ClosureType::operator=`).

Example:

```
auto x = 0;
auto l0 = [copy = x]() mutable {};
auto l1 = []() mutable {};

static_assert(not std::is_copy_assignable_v<decltype(l0)>);
static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable_v<decltype(std::ref(x))>);
static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable_v<decltype(l1)>);
```

I'm asking for the rationale behind this choice: Why is the `operator=` deleted? Particularly in scenarios, where it could be defaulted i.e. the lambda is `mutable` and all captures are copy-assignable themselves (e.g. `l0` in the example above)?

I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379369/emulate-copy-assignment-operator-for-lambdas-in-c) related question for non-`mutable` lambdas. But I'd like to understand the decision rather than working around it.

Comment: Mutable in a lasagna only means that the captured variables are mutable/ non const

Comment: Probably because every none empty-capture lambda type has a unique instance. What are you going to assign to it other than the already assigned unique instance?

Comment: The instance doesn't have to be unique. Example: `auto make(int s) { return [x = s]() mutable {}; }`.

Comment: `mutable` affects the call operator; it has nothing to do with the member variables and thus *shouldn’t* affect any special member functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it was not proposed. Lambdas entered the language much weaker than the function objects they are sugar for and slowly are gaining back functionality. With respect to the special member functions, [P0624](http://wg21.link/p0624) proposed adding assignability and default-constructibility for captureless lambdas. Only default-constructibility was proposed in R0, because that is what the author needed and arguably is the most obvious deficiency, but assignability was proposed in R1 based on committee feedback.

Default-constructibility for lambdas with captures certainly is consistent with the language:

```
auto x1 = [i = 1]() { return i; };
static_assert(not std::is_default_constructible_v<decltype(x1)>); // why??

struct { int i = 1; auto operator()() { return i; } } x2;
static_assert(std::is_default_constructible_v<decltype(x2)>);
```

Assignability also is consistent and useful. As just one example that comes to mind, there was a proposal at some point to have an analogue of `std::default_delete` for allocators, i.e. a type that could be used as a template parameter to `std::unique_ptr` for allocator-allocated pointers. You could imagine using a lambda to capture the allocator and use it for such a purpose:

```
auto allocator_delete(auto& allocator) {
    using traits = typename std::allocator_traits<std::decay_t<decltype(allocator)>>;
    return [alloc=std::ref(allocator)](typename traits::pointer p) { traits::deallocate(alloc, p, 1); };
}
template<class Alloc> using allocator_deleter_t = decltype(allocator_delete(std::declval<Alloc&>()));
static_assert(not std::is_move_assignable_v<std::unique_ptr<int, allocator_deleter_t<std::allocator<int>>>>);
// why??
```

But you cannot rebind (move-assign to) this `unique_ptr`, because the lambda artificially deletes assignment, even though its capture state allows it. Rewrite this as a function object type and the `unique_ptr` is assignable, with generated assignment operators for the function object type.

That's just one example, but hopefully it clarifies that whether or not you want to assign to the capture state (the `std::ref(allocator)`) is not the same as what the call operator is allowed to do to the capture state. (The linked question's answer is wrong.)